# Ant Chalk Cleanup

Tags: cleaning, pest-control

I read a few articles on Google and this [Lifehack post](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/3940/pest-control-natural-method-of-ant-control-howto) on alternatives for Ant/Bug control. How would I properly clean up ant chalk that has been used on hard wood? I previously used latex gloves, a good cloth, water/soap and wiped the floor clean, I then disposed of it safely. Is that the proper procedure to remove Any Chalk from the floor? If not, how do I do it?

**Sorry if this is the wrong forum for this. I couldn't find a suitable forum and other sites require you to sign up and I already had an account here. If this is the wrong forum, close it, or kindly move it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do what you have been doing with a few alternations:**

> used latex gloves, a good cloth, water/soap and wiped the floor clean

Some other added methods:

- Utilize proper ventilation and use masks, so that this dust does not damage your lungs.
- Use suction, i.e. a vaccuum cleaner with nozzle  and proper filter to suck up the bulk. This also can grab the dust in the crevices.
- Use a brush to loosen any particles that may be residing deeper or just need some friction to be removed. To vacuum while brushing also helps.
- Change water frequently so that you do not wipe the dust back onto the floor.